# Setup FreshTomato 2021.2 on R7000 to forward traffic from internet through OpenVPN tunnel

Tags: networking, iptables, tomato

With FreshTomato 2021.2 on R7000, I'm trying to allow port forwarding (80/443) inside OpenVPN client to able to reach a device on my LAN.

Here's the current status of iptables (iptables -S):

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N shlimit
-N upnp
-N wanin
-N wanout
-A INPUT -i tun21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j shlimit
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i br0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun11 -m state --state NEW -j wanin
-A FORWARD -i tun21 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o tun11 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m account --aaddr 21.9.12.0/255.255.255.0 --aname lan
-A FORWARD -i br0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i vlan2 -j wanin
-A FORWARD -o vlan2 -j wanout
-A FORWARD -i vlan3 -j wanin
-A FORWARD -o vlan3 -j wanout
-A FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i vlan2 -j upnp
-A shlimit -m recent --set --name shlimit --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource
-A shlimit -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 4 --name shlimit --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -j DROP
-A upnp -d 21.9.12.153/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 9308 -j ACCEPT
-A upnp -d 21.9.12.153/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 9305 -j ACCEPT
-A upnp -d 21.9.12.92/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 59319 -j ACCEPT
-A wanin -d 21.9.12.211/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A wanin -d 21.9.12.211/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A wanin -d 21.9.12.211/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A wanin -d 21.9.12.211/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A wanin -d 21.9.12.211/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 64246 -j ACCEPT
-A wanin -d 21.9.12.211/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 64246 -j ACCEPT
```

My LAN ip is on 21.9.12.0. My VPN client is known as tun11. For me it seems ok, but I'm unable to connect. Any suggestion? I'm totally stuck.

UPDATE:
Outgoing traffic from the VPN works fine and the public IP via VPN is 172.94.**.***.

I want to be able to access my lan server (21.9.12.211) on port 80 and 443.

When I do a curl 172.94.**.*** from external, I have a Couldn't connect to server response.

But telnet connects fine (TCP), but when I start HTTP request it is disconnected:

```
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.0
    




Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: Please give some details on what happens when you try connecting, how you are connecting, where you are located versus where this system is and what the internet and network settings are.

Comment: I've tried to update. Sorry for my poor english

Comment: Are the right ports open and protocols visible on the outside IP? If Telnet works but curl doesn't, that sounds like you don't have the correct ports open and forwarded.

Comment: did you mean these rules: -A wanin -d 21.9.12.211/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A wanin -d 21.9.12.211/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A wanin -d 21.9.12.211/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A wanin -d 21.9.12.211/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

Comment: I have made a little progress, HTTP works fine, but not HTTPS...